# C arithmetic overflow difference between 32bit and 64bit?

Tags: c, math, 64-bit, overflow, 32-bit

I wonder if there is any difference by checking arithmetic overflows for 32bit and 64bit?
(except the limits..)

For example for 32 bit multiplication `a * b`:

```
if(b > 0 && a > UINT32_MAX_VALUE / b) {
//Overflow
}
```

Can I use the same logic for 64 bit multiplication?
like:

```
if(b > 0 && a > UINT64_MAX_VALUE / b) {
//Overflow
}
```

are there any traps when I have to check 64 bit overflow with signed / unsigned?

Comment: No, the principle is exactly the same. Only the constants differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it for yourself. What's a 32-bit `int` vs a 64-bit `int`? We know an `int` is an `int`, it can contain the same thing and follows the same rules, but one has more bits.

Think about a `char` vs. a `short` (on a 32-bit system).

```
unsigned char cmax  = 0xFF;   // 1111 1111(2) = 255(10)

unsigned short imax = 0xFFFF; // 1111 1111 1111 1111(2) = 65535(10)
```

If I add 1 to either of these they will overflow, one it twice the size of the other. Do I need to do anything special to check for overflow in one case vs the other?  No.

Your example differs as it's two `int`s of course, but the reasoning is the same.